# Strange behavior of MS Excel finding origin of ctrl+shift+backspace keyboard shortcut

Tags: microsoft-excel, keyboard-shortcuts, shortcuts

While answering [Keyboard shortcut to delete a word at a time in a cell](https://superuser.com/questions/1335185/keyboard-shortcut-to-delete-a-word-at-a-time-in-a-cell?noredirect=1#comment1996745_1335185), I found that a shortcut <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>Backspace</kbd> is working for me to delete one word left to cursor position.

However, when I tested this shortcut on another system with the same version of MS Office installed, this shortcut didn’t work. Also, I didn’t find any documentation from Microsoft about this shortcut.

To identify what is causing this shortcut to work, I reset all customizations, deactivated all add-ins and closed `AutoHotKey`. But this shortcut is still working.

What else can be done to identify what is causing this shortcut to work.

Here are version/build details of MS Office installed on my system..

[image]

[image]

[image]

List of processes running on system when I tested shortcut.

[image]

Comment: So, the plot thickens! This is indeed puzzling. Did you try restarting windows after all your changes?

Comment: @robinCTS Restarted after your comment. Shortcut is still working.

Comment: Any other software installed that could possibly be doing this?

Comment: @robinCTS I closed/killed all software and kept MS Excel and Process Explorer (sysinternals) running. I can still use shortcut. I have also added an image of all processes running while I tested it.

Comment: Assuming that you are talking about the text cursor and not the cell cursor, does anything happen when you press the same key combination while not editing cell contents?

Comment: And what happens if you press just shift + backspace in the same scenario? CTRL + backspace is documented shortcut for recentering the scrollbars on the active cell.

Comment: @PFitz In not-editing mode, both (shift + backspace) and (ctrl + backspace) do not do anything. While editing (shift + backspace) deletes one character from left, (ctrl + backspace) does not do anything.

Comment: Is the word being highlighted before it is deleted? It sounds like a left arrow key is being registered in there somehow. Another possibility (bit of a guess here) is that it is treating the inputs as coming from an on-screen touch keyboard. The behavior sounds a lot like tap-swipe gestures.

Comment: No, word is not highlighted. It works same as we see in MS Word when press `CTRL + Backspace`. This is my work PC and I have never used on screen keyboard on this system. It is not making any problem, I am just curious to find why it is happening. It there a way to check what happens when i press the key combination. Some applications create hooks to handle keys differently (E.g. AutoHotKey). It there a way to list any such hook installed on my system? I do use AutoHotKey and SQL Assistant; but both of them were killed when I tested shortcut.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Today I took a system, formatted it and installed Win 10 Enterprise. First software I installed was MS Office 365 (latest version downloaded with web installer). And it turned out the `Ctrl + Shift + BackSpace` is still deleting whole word at left side of cursor.

Though I didn't find any documentation to support this; but it seems that this feature is added in MS Excel. I am using MS Office 365 Pro Plus 32-bit (Version 1810).

Answer (score -1):

**My Solution is based on Excel version 2007, 2010, 2013 & 2016. I've never tried Office 365.**

The question seeks to answer why a keyboard shortcut works on one system but not another.  There are a lot of potential conflicts with shortcuts, and the cause can be difficult to root out.  This can be treated as an exercise to determine the cause.  But if the objective is a working shortcut, another solution is to just try a different shortcut that may be less susceptible to conflict.

I never came across <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Backspace</kbd> to delete the word to the left of the cursor in an Excel cell. But I can suggest another shortcut.  A reliable way to do it (just one extra keystroke):

- Select the word with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Left</kbd> (repeated use selects multiple words).
- Then use <kbd>Delete</kbd> or <kbd>Backspace</kbd> to remove the whole selection.

Comment: Just write your concern to down vote this !!

Comment: @fixer1234,,  thanks for useful edits,, it enhances the scope of the answer ☺